# Why does git diff show solitary CRs when file's line endings are correct CRLFs?

Tags: git, cygwin

The problem is:
git diff shows solitary CRs but there are none in reality. Does this mean that committing the changes will cause trouble?

```
$ git diff
index bla bla
--- a/filename
+++ b/filename
@@ etc
text
text
text
new text^M
text
text
text
```

The interpretation I have of this output is that the new line ends with CR-CR-LF instead of properly ending with just CR-LF, but that is not the case.

Inspecting the files in various ways shows that the new text has a correct CR-LF pair just like the lines before and after do. For example, inspecting the file using hexdump shows correct CR-LF pairs throughout.

The "^M"s are showing on some but not all pending changes. When there is a "^M" it is appended to every 'new' line of the change. All the lines of all the files in this project end with CR-LF, it is only some of the recent changes that are incorrectly displayed by git diff. This is not a bogus git status issue; the only files appearing with unstaged changes in git status are legitimately changed.

All of git's newline-related config options are at their default settings. I will emphasize that even though it might be good to do in the future, I have not set core.autocrlf to true as is apparently advised for Windows. The previous 10 commits didn't have such problems and the config options have always been the same.

There are no .gitattributes files locally. There is no remote repo yet so there isn't no .gitattributes there either. This is confirmed by checking which attributes might be set on the file using git check-attributes, which outputs no attributes at all for files showing this problem. Again the previous 10 commits didn't have problems with "^M"s popping up for no reason in the diff.

I often check my "git diff" before committing in case I might prefer to do "git add -p" and separate some changes from others, or perhaps not commit that extra noisy log line I might have added temporarily. This is how I've noticed the troublesome git diff output at this time.

I may wish to push my code to GitHub and expose my code to criticism, so it would be nice if I could convince "git diff" that everything is fine, if everything in fact is fine.

The environment is Cygwin updated around 12/27/14, using the GIT that comes from Cygwin, and the filesystem is mounted as "binary" (which is a Cygwin thing preserves line endings).

Comment: " I have not set core.autocrlf to true as is apparently advised for Window": so `git config core.autocrlf` returns nothing? Set it to false, just to be sure: `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Comment: git config -l doesn't show a setting for core.autocrlf. From what I've read, changing it now would not affect anything, unless I did additional steps, which I don't believe would apply here.

Comment: I just now set core.autocrlf flag to true, but it did not change how "git diff" shows the pending changes on my files.

Comment: I agree, that wouldn't change anything for the existing index. Could you try resetting said index and redoing your changes, to see if the issue persists. Provided you did set core.autocrlf to false off course: Not true. False. `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Comment: The only "redo" I'm willing to do is "git stash save" then "git stash pop". Since git diff generates a bad diff I wouldn't want to create a patch, then reset, then apply the patch.

Comment: How did you tell git that you consider CRLF to be proper line endings?  Behavior is expected if git uses the default of LF.

Comment: If it was somehow going hardcore about an LF line ending, ALL of the lines would display "^M" at the end in git diff and in any other context where git displays them, right?

Answer (score 1):

Initial conditions:

Changes have been made to files. Files have CRLF line endings. "git diff" seems confused.

Step 1: generate a patch using "git difftool -x "/usr/bin/diff -u" -y > patchfile

Step 2: Add configs as follows (partial git config -l output)

```
core.autocrlf=false
core.eol=lf
```

Step 3: git checkout -- any_changed_file

-> At this point the only copy of the edits is in the patchfile from step 1

Step 4: Change all files to LF line endings and commit same.

Step 5: Change all line endings in the patch from step 1 to LF as well.

Step 6: Apply the patch from step 1

-> The patch index lines will look a little hairy but the patch utility won't get confused.

At this point the blobs in the repo and the changes to be applied are in the format that GIT likes. Now normal procedures can be followed to commit the changes. In my case, I had been lax in making separate commits for separate changes so I had to use git add -p and then commit for several rounds.

Follow up step: Make sure Eclipse/YourEditor is configured to create new files with LF line endings in the future. If it cannot be configured this way then get rid of the editor. One major, fairly popular IDE (NOT Notepad) had to be discarded because I discovered that it only did "native" line endings, which meant I could not use it to write bash scripts.

Tentatively, there are undocumented heuristics within GIT that interact with 3 or 4 GIT configuration settings to produce GIT's behavior and the easy, non-subtle case is when everything is geared towards LF line endings.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Git assumes a line to be 0 or more characters, followed by a newline
(LF). When you use Carriage Return, Line Feed (CRLF) line endings, Git sees this
as a change to the file. So on a diff when you see

```
new text^M
text
```

What you are seeing is a representation of a CR (^M), followed by a literal LF.
If the LF was not there you would see this

```
new text^Mtext
```

The best way to fix these find of problems is to simply use LF line endings with
all of your files. All modern text editors (read: not Notepad) support this.
However if you cannot or will not do this, you can add this to your
`~/.gitconfig`

```
[core]
whitespace = cr-at-eol
```

Comment: This is not the answer because only half of the changes I have pending have the "^M" on the added lines. Other files have added lines and they don't display "^M" on the changes in git diff. BTW Eclipse defaults to CRLF on Windows even if you define your project to be using Cygwin GCC. Defining a project to use Cygwin GCC *could* have been a trigger to use Unix line endings, but it isn't.

Comment: I intend to convert the project to LF line endings after I have an orderly commit of the current changes.

Comment: What would I try that would make your answer apply? Basically the state of the project is that I have changes I wish to commit, but 'git diff' is causing me to believe that it may make the text inconsistent. I cannot "try" making all my files have LF endings YET, and I've been very clear about this. If "git diff" cannot handle displaying CRLF-delimited line insertions in the middle of an existing-in-the-repo CRLF-delimited file, then it implies that commits of such files can't be handled properly either.